# How to add Conditional non-nullable field in GraphQL schema?

Tags: graphql, schema

```
type Review { 
   rating: Int!,
   text: String! 
}
```

I want to achieve - only one field can be nullable between rating and text or only one field would be non-nullable between rating and text in "Review" type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Interface](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces) to model such behaviour in GraphQL. If I understand you correctly, it seems you want to have several type of Review such as :

```
type RatingBasedReview {
    rating  : Int!
}

type TextBasedReview {
    text   : String!
}
```

First define a common interface for all the Review:

```
interface Review {

}
```

and each sub types implements it :

```
type RatingBasedReview implements Review {
    rating  : Int!
}

type TextBasedReview implements Review {
    text   : String!
}
```

The client can then use [inline fragments](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#inline-fragments) syntax to specify what actual sub-types it want to query.

Comment: A union would also work and would be necessary if there are no common fields since an interface must define at least one field. `interface Review { }` is not valid syntax.